# Query Laravel for graph

Tags: laravel

[image][image]I hope someone can help me. I came across a very complex Laravel query and I don't know how to get out of it.
My problem is that in the database I would like to group a series of columns so that the results of these groups are unique because they are repeated and select data from other columns belonging to these groups e.g. warehouse column is repeated 3 times I would like it to be displayed once, listing all the warehouse audit dates in another column and the results of these dates in another column. I wrote like this but I don't get the result. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong, thank you very much..  I would like to get some kind of graph..

Query :

```
$audit = DB::table('esiti_audit')->where('employee', $name)
        ->select('master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea')        
        ->groupByRaw('master_zone,subarea,microarea')
        ->orderByDesc('data_audit')->select('data_audit', 'esito')
        ->get();
```

Comment: you have two `select` in your code, also format your code to be more readable.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, I know I have two selects, the point is that I would like to select the results of these groups obtaining example: Areas 1 date 16 02 2021 Positive
date 02 17 2021
negative and so on for each group

Comment: So as to then obtain a kind of graphic with css in the front

Comment: You can't have two select, it makes no sense

Comment: $audit = DB::table('esiti_audit')->where('employee', $name)->groupByRaw('master_zone,subarea,microarea')
            ->orderByDesc('data_audit')->select('data_audit', 'esito')->get(); I did this but I only found a date and an outcome for these groups, instead I would like all the outcomes and dates for these groups

Comment: The second select will just append to the first one, you can do `->select('master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea', 'data_audit', 'esito')` it's the exact same result

Comment: ok, but I don't have all the results should I loop with a foreach?

Comment: you can try group_concat function, it will concatenate all grouped values separated by a comma, perhaps it's what you want to achieve but i'm not sure

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: I would like to obtain all the results of the queried columns of the requested groups, for example

Area 1 09.08 positive 07.08 negative 06/08 positive. Area 1 is a group.

Area 2 09.08 negative 07.08 positive 06/08 negative.

and so on

Comment: @Morex you can't return multiple results from the same group, unless you `group_concat` the results into a comma separated list for each group. So you would have `Area 1 | "09.08,07.08"` and `Area 2 | "09.08,07.08"`. But if you need all the results and you are not running some aggregate, WHY are you grouping in the first place?

Comment: I have attached an image to help you understand how I would like the results to come out

Comment: again grouping only makes your life harder here, you need ALL dates with ALL statuses, grab them from your database and use collections/arrays to sort your dates into each area

Comment: Please can you give me code an example ? I'm going crazy

Comment: I have attached an image db to help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build the structure you need in Areas and days:

```php
$audits = DB::table('esiti_audit')->select([
    'master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea',
    'data_audit', 'esito'
  ])
  ->where('employee', $name)
  ->orderByDesc('data_audit')
  ->get()->toArray();

$data = [];

foreach($audits as $audit) {
  // build this into a key or nested arrays, up to the use case
  $areaKey = "{$audit['master_zone']}|{$audit['subarea']}|{$audit['microarea']}";

  $data[$areaKey][] = [
    'status' => $audit['esito'],
    'date' => $audit['data_audit']
  ];
}

// pass $data to your view and loop as @foreach($data as $area => $audits)
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array ... gives me this error

Comment: either turn `$audit['...']` into `$audit->...` or make $audit an array

Comment: he won't let me, but because My God

Comment: nothing gives me the same error...

Comment: what is "same error"? read where the error happens and fix it

Comment: thank you very much you were right solved is object